# multiphase from passing data value step1 to step2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am not able to pass message from step1 of my form to step2 My console deliver the message in the div check-ok. But this message block the process in step1 and is written on step1. Thanks to help me how to resolve this problem.

```
      if (v.form()) {
    var data = {
    'civility'   : jQuery("input[name=civility]:checked", "#to-bc-clt").val(),
    'society'    : jQuery('#society').val(),
    'firstName'  : jQuery('#firstName').val(),
    'lastName'   : jQuery('#lastName').val(),
    'email'      : jQuery('#email').val(),
    };

jQuery.ajax({
url : '/mySite/VerifRep/parsers/check.php',
method : 'POST',
type    : 'POST',
data : data,


success : function(data){
  if (data != 'passed') {
    jQuery('#messages-errors').html(data);
    }  
  if (data == 'passed') {
    $(".frm").hide("fast");
    $("#step2").show("slow");
    $(".open1").css("display","none");
    $(".open2").css("display","inline-block");

     $("#check-ok").html(data);

    }
},
error : function(){
    alert('Not working.'); }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You should remove `,` at end of `'email'      : jQuery('#email').val(),` line

Comment: Thanks @CMedina --> correction made. But not resolve my problem.

Comment: You means that step 2  is faster than step 1?

Comment: Faster ? I retrieve my datas but they don't pass in step 2 my echo json is visible on step1 and stop multiphase process